# LLVM getBackedgeTakenCount() behavior

Tags: optimization, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have the following loop

```
for(i=5;i<5000;i++){


}
```

I am using getBackedgeTakenCount() from Scalar Evolution. The above loop has determinable loop count, then why is the function giving me Cannot Compute? Am I missing something.

I have used following analysis

```
LI = &getAnalysis<LoopInfo>();
SE = &getAnalysis<ScalarEvolution>();
```

Comment: This is an infinite loop, since `i` doesn't change

Comment: sorry its i++ and still gives cannot compute